# vscode.showInformationMessage - how to add a header to message

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am publishing a vscode extension and have a simple header and message to show up.
the message and the items are show as expected, but i couldn't find the way to add a header with text.
how can I do this? should I use a different message method?
the current code:

```
    const header = { title: 'Confirmation Needed' };               
    return vscode.window.showInformationMessage(text, ...["Ok", "Cancel"]);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the *modal* option:

```js
const header = "Message Header";
const options: vscode.MessageOptions = { detail: 'Message Description', modal: true };
vscode.window.showInformationMessage(header, options, ...["Ok"]).then((item)=>{
    console.log(item);
});
```

Which will look like this:
[image: modal with "OK" and "cancel" button]

Note, that *item* will contain the string of the pressed button, but will be **undefined** if the user clicks on "Cancel".

---

Unfortunately, it is not be possible to do this without the modal dialog, according to the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#MessageOptions)

Comment: thanks for your replay, i want to ask - if i do care about the appearance of the dialog, is there a way to give up on the title, and use the dialog with its UI, but use the modal behavior to block activity before confirmation? or is there a way to style the dialog?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think that it is possible to style the dialog using the vscode-api(referring to [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-capabilities/overview#restrictions) page).